# ¿Como puedo seleccionar una fila agregar mediante ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Este es el código para seleccionar

```
$('#example tr').on('click', function () {
  var dato = $(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').html();
  alert(dato);
});
```

funciona bien cuando la tabla esta cargada con datos en duro por ejemplo:

```
<table id="example>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Juan</td>
    <td>Perez</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

pero al momento de agregar filas por ajax no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

has esto:

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  var dato = $(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').html();
  alert(dato);
});
```

como tu tabla es dinámica, te explico porque:

ya que los elementos no existen estos no obtienen un evento, ya que no existen. Lo mejor que hay que hacer es seleccionar un elemento existente y decirle que todo elemento `tr` va obtener un evento